# How can I make eyes and eyelids follow the rig

Tags: weight-painting, rigify

After generating a rig and aligning it and parenting to automatic weight paints I've run into a couple of issues. However I'm unsure if this is a weight problem that automatic weight paints can't solve or a parenting problem I tried weight painting the eyeballs and eyelids myself but no results so I can't seem to get it follow the rig when I rotate the head. Is there anything I can do about this? What am I doing wrong?

Here's the file:
https://workupload.com/file/HyKmvezGskS

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have extra vertex groups eyes, if removed they will work correctly.[image: fixed model]

You're using rigify for your character and parented the eyes with automatic weights, they are usually parented to MCH.Eye bones.
For the eyelids you need to hide every part of the mesh except them, then you choose the head bone (DEF-spine.006) and press Ctrl+x to set weight.

I recommend removing all vertex groups and weights that you don't need, such as body and clothing hair weights. There are over 1.6 million polygons in your file, vertex groups can make it work slower.
You have a hair system there, this could be the cause of the lags.
(Also you can delete a few armature modifiers)[image: Armature modifiers]

Hope this helps, this was my first answer on Stack Exchange.

Comment: WOW! Well, that would explain why I have lag so much when I do anything. Feels so much better now also I didn't know made so many modifiers. Explains a lot. (recently learned that too can cause lag on my research) Thank you!

Comment: @William
Rigify can generate the rig faster by excluding the face bones if it takes too long.
A custom face rig can be created with a few bones and the Rigify face can be deleted. The eyes can be rigged with a damped track bone constraint.
Please mark this answer as correct if it solved your problem, so others can find it too.

Comment: Right. My bad still learning how to use this site features. So in short I can delete some bones to make a faster generating rig and then create less bones that can help control the face so that it doesn't also clutter my screen. Good to know. (I was too afraid to delete much of anything without knowing first if it would mess up something else and make it unusable.) Ty

Comment: Yeah, my experience with Rigify was sitting and trying to figure out what it doesn't like about leg bones. The pelvis bones were connected incorrectly.
Now, I'm trying to create a fully custom IK rig without Rigify. That's even more challenging.
You can switch to Blender 4.0, rigging is much easier there.
CGdive has some really helpful tutorials on rigging.
There is a playlist on his channel: [Rigify 4.0](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdcL5aF8ZcJt1GvL-Fcxy-fPgEFG-1fLp&si=-vvcilJUsiqsYp4U)